# ERROR: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,

Tags: 18.04, apache2

I'm facing a problem after using

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2

   apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-09-15 04:16:20 IST; 10s ago
  Process: 7043 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7048 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7053 (apache2)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 4559)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─7053 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─7054 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─7055 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─7056 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─7057 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─7058 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Sep 15 04:16:20 deb-Inspiron-3542 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP
Server... Sep 15 04:16:20 deb-Inspiron-3542 apachectl[7048]:
**AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, us** Sep 15 04:16:20 deb-Inspiron-3542
systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

What is the better way to overcome that?

Thanks
Debajyoti

Comment: It's not an error, it's an warning. Do you experience any problems? For a testing environment it may not be relevant. The workaround is to explicitly set the FQDN.

Comment: Yes when I use my ip address in URL to start it shows....


`handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);`

Comment: That points in the direction of missing php support in the webserver. Please [edit] your question to include more information about your configuration, and what you actually see.

Comment: Probably you need to add `ServerName localhost` or (anything other instead localhost) at server level (not in some VirtualHost tags) in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.